# How can I Fill an Input with "Shadow Root (closed)" using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, automation, puppeteer

I've been trying to fill this input `(#inputEmail)` that is inside Shadow-Root with Puppeteer

Here is how the HTML looks like:

[image: code_example]

```html
<login-form id="form"></login-form>
#shadow-root (closed)
    <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputEmail" name="" class="form-control" tabindex="1" placeholder="email@example.com" value="" autocomplete="off" autofocus="true" required="">
        <label id="inputEmailTooltip" class="error" style="display: none">Required Field</label>
    </div>
<login-form id="form"></login-form>
```

I've tried something like this on Puppeteer:

```
const input = await $(page, `form::id(#inputEmail)`);
```

And got the error `'form::id(#inputEmail)' is not a valid selector.`

I've also tried

```js
const emailInput = document.querySelector('#form').shadowRoot.querySelector('#inputEmail')
```

And got the error below

```
    const emailInput = document.querySelector('#form').shadowRoot.querySelector('#inputEmail')
                       ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

How could I target this input using Puppeteer or any library such as [puppeteer-shadow-selector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-shadow-selector)?

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm it but you should be able to use the builtin `pierce` selector:

```js
await page.type('pierce/#inputEmail', 'myemailvalue');
```